# Magento 1.9 custom module 404 error after IP change

Tags: magento-1.9, module, extensions, http-error-404

I have created custom module for my application the urls for which were working correctly.

Due to some issue with the server the IP had to be changed after which all the extension URLS have stopped working even the installed ones.

I have tried removing cache folder, setting up website again, even creating the module again as well.

But the frontend urls are still throwing the 404 error.

Please help with the above issue.

Thanks

Comment: have you reindex the data ?

Comment: Yes have reindexed and removed cache multiple times.

Comment: Can you check the htaccess is placed correctly or not?

Comment: Checked and recreated the htaccess, still the same issue.

Comment: Sounds like your domain is not being resolved to the new IP address.

Comment: There is no domain, website is working on IP